# How can I export all item ID's, Metadata and Names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-forge

I am attempting to export a list of all item IDs, and metadata from 
minecraft. I am using the FTB Unleashed pack.
What I want is to write to file:

```
351:1 Ink Sac
351:2 Rose Red
...
368:0 Ender Pearl
369:0 Blaze Rod
...
2174:0 Naga Stone
```

Or something that I can convert to that with some regex etc.

NEI, and Item Resolver both only export item IDs.
However this is not useful to me because some mod, heavily use the metadata value, to store a different item in the same ID space. The Vanilla Dye is an example of this.

I am coming the the conclusion I may just have to make it myself.

I would like this for computercraft fun.
I many computercraft things return only the item id / metadata eg the ME Bridge and [Interactive Sorter](http://ftbwiki.org/Interactive_Sorter). Other computer craft mods (AE Peripheral, OpenCCsensors) do handle item names. However I am unwilling to add mods to the server.
If a there is a mod I can use in single player to export all the ID, metadata and names, then I can use a computercraft program to parse it, that can run on the server. (I already have one working for ID/Name)

Comment: Perhap i could get it out of the texture files somehow?

Comment: No, texture files contain no ID information.

Comment: Can I ask you to edit your answer to include why you want this list? That will help us help you better, since there may be alternative solutions that you don't know about. If you tell us the problem you're trying to solve with this export list, we may be able to solve your actual problem better.

Comment: SevenSidedDie. Editted. I considered adding this when I created the topic, but I don't think it is relevant. I don't want a different solution to my problem. I want a list of IDs, Metadata and Names.

Comment: Cool, that is helpful. Including that info will also *prevent* people from giving "helpful" alternatives that don't give you an ID list. :) (Such as NEI's tooltips showing IDs. Useful, but too limited for your purposes.)

Comment: SevenSidedDie: Fair point.

Comment: Looking at the code, this is a surprisingly nontrivial problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a mod, [ItemDumper for 1.5.2](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/files/ItemDumper.zip), (and [for 1.4.7](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rq91496leyp5nzp/ItemDumperv1.4.7.zip)) to serve this purpose for you.
It is pretty hacky, I wouldn't recommend you keep it loaded while just playing.

Install it in the usual way.

When you log in to a world it will dump out all the ID's, metadata, name and tool tip,
in the form
`<id>:<metadata> = <name> = <tooltip>`
into a file called "ItemDump.txt" in your current working directory,
(for FTB, this is the folder specified as the start up path, in the launcher).

Sample output:

```
...
688:0 = Monazit Ore =  Monazit Ore (#0688)
690:0 = MFFS Control System =  MFFS Control System (#0690)
900:0 = ME Cable - Blue =  ME Cable - Blue (#0900/0)
900:1 = ME Pattern Provider =  ME Pattern Provider (#0900/1)
900:2 = ME Controller =  ME Controller (#0900/2)
900:3 = ME Drive =  ME Drive (#0900/3)
...
```

The tooltip is probably useless.

Note that it doesn't catch all the different metadata values a item can incure from being damaged. Only those that can be spawned (by search) in creative mode.

[The source code, released under MIT License.](http://pastebin.com/8Zev1pdp)

It has at least one bug. It does not dump the ID's for any items that do not show up in the Creative Mod, item search.
This includes, for example, Forge MultiPart blocks.
At somestage I may fix this, I would need to work out how NEI gets a list of items. I suspect there is some kind of second Forge item list.

<sub>Thanks to [Gunther Struyf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/36552/gunther-struyf) , for compiling and uploading the 1.4.7 version.</sub>

Comment: Is this open source?

Comment: sure, why not. MIT License, 
I've just pastebinned the 2 files that have any vaguely meaning full cotnent in them. It is a piece of hackery.
 http://pastebin.com/8Zev1pdp

Comment: I've recompiled this to work for 1.4.7, no changes needed: [ItemDumper for 1.4.7](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rq91496leyp5nzp/ItemDumperv1.4.7.zip)

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: Nice, cool. Shall I edit that into my answer so people can fine easier?

Comment: sure, why not, it's your code anyways

Comment: `When you log in to a world it will dump` So you need to be able to get the game running? That’s not going to help if ID conflicts are preventing the game from starting at all.

Comment: Indeed it will not. It's not for that. The OP wanted it for computercraft uses. If you a looking for how to find ID conflicts then I'm sure there is another question for that. ID conflicts don't require knowing the damage value either.

Answer (score 6):

Not Enough Items can help you create a data dump. Launch your Minecraft, and go into a world. Access your inventory and go into the options (bottom left corner). Go to Block/Item settings, and create the dump by hitting "Dump ID Map Now". The dump will be created at your .minecraft folder. Open the .txt file and it will show you all the blocks loaded at the time of dumping.

You will see something like this:

```
Block. Name: tile.stone. ID: 1
```

It does not display metadata.

Comment: NEI expanded its metadata support in general when it updated for 1.6.2, so it may dump metadata now (I will check later), but that's not relevant to 1.5.2 of course.

Comment: As stated in the question I've tried this. Though this information is useful to others. ItemResolver's Dump is better. As well as displaying name, it shows class, and ToolTip (but still not meta)

Comment: Also, NEI’s dump is only useful if you can get the game running. If you can get that far, there are few if any conflicts. Most ID conflicts will prevent starting the game at all, thus making the NEI dump useless.